# Consuming API and store results to database

Tags: spring, database, rest, consuming

I need to consume this API: https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers and after consuming, I have to store it in the database, but only with next fields: internal id, name, description and mean value of the temperature. Any ideas or advice?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to have your Model only containing those attributes so that Spring only deserialize them from JSON to object. Something like the following:

```
public class YourModel {
   private long id;
   private String name;
   private String description;
}
```

Then in your Service you would have:

```
ResponseEntity<YourModel> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, YourModel.class);
```

You can then either save `YourModel` directly to the database (first you need to add some @Annotations if you want to rely on JPA) or you may build another more suited model to your use case.